# i get 'Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory' when i upload file to the server

Tags: javascript, express, multer

i got this error when trying to upload an image using multer.
this is my fileStorage settings:

```
const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, 'images');
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + '-' + file.originalname);
  }
});
```

and this is the middleware of multer

```
app.use(
  multer({ storage: fileStorage, fileFilter: fileFilter }).single('image')
);
```

Comment: And the directory "images" exists? Also, what OS are you running your server on?

Comment: it exist, and windows os